# Spring Security: Redirect to Login Page in case of 401

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

I have an application that exposes a REST API and is secured using Spring Security. Is there a way to automatically redirect the client (from the server side) to the login page if a request sent to my server results in 401 - unauthorised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the following elements to my Spring Security XML under an `http` node:

```
<security:access-denied-handler error-page="/#/login"  />
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/#/login" session-fixation-protection="changeSessionId" />
```

Answer (score 11):

For `spring-security` application based on `spring-boot`.

**Define a handler bean:**

```
@Component
public class CommenceEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 565662170056829238L;

    // invoked when user tries to access a secured REST resource without supplying any credentials,
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        // send a json object, with http code 401,
        // response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");

        // redirect to login page, for non-ajax request,
        response.sendRedirect("/login.html");
    }
}
```

**In security config class (e.g `WebSecurityConfig`):**

Autowire the bean:

```
@Autowired
private CommenceEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler; // handle unauthorized request,
```

Specify handler:

```
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and() // excepion handler,
```

**Tips:**

- This is suitable only for non-ajax request,
- For ajax request, better return `401` code, and let the frontend handle it.
  If you want to use `401` response, in `CommenceEntryPoint.commence()` just use `response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");` instead of `response.sendRedirect()`.

Comment: You don't need to create your own component. Instead, you can use this: `.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify how your application handles exception or HTTP status codes by specifying it in error-page element of web.xml

eg: web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/login.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Same way you handle other HTTP status code viz 404 for page not found page.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this using java/annotaion based configuration ?